# Membership renewal receipt template not showing membership start- and end dates

Tags: civimember, templates, renewals, 5.15.2

In the membership renewal (online) receipt template, it says, here,

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/xml/templates/message_templates/membership_online_receipt_text.tpl#L68

```
{foreach from=$value item=line}
   [....]
   {$line.start_date|string_format:"%20s"} 
   {$line.end_date|string_format:"%20s"}
{/foreach}
```

That just prints blanks in all my renewals:

```
===========================================================
Membership Fee
===========================================================
Item                                  Fee  Membership Start Date  Membership End Date
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 - Test X Membership...        $220.00 USD                                            

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Same for the HTML and PDF versions.

Membership *signup* receipts work fine, but they use

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/xml/templates/message_templates/membership_online_receipt_text.tpl#L18

```
{if $mem_start_date}{ts}Membership Start Date{/ts}: {$mem_start_date|crmDate}
```

Does anyone else have this problem ? What could it be ?

Comment: Two things to check:
Have you checked if your template is overridden?
(See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/message-templates/#modifying-system-workflow-message-templates)
Have you tried to replicate this on a demo or fresh install?

Comment: @lolcode - thanks - yes, they are overridden, but use the same code on those spots. I didn't yet try to replicate it on a fresh install.